# Listener not called when dialog "update Google Play Services" is prompted

Tags: android, google-play-services, kotlin, google-signin

I'm using a `GoogleApiClient` built with `enableAutoManage`:

```
GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
  .enableAutoManage(activity) { result ->
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
      GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().showErrorDialogFragment(activity, result.errorCode, 0)
    }
    else {
      try {
        result.startResolutionForResult(activity, errorResolutionRequestCode)
      } catch (e: SendIntentException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e)
      }
    }
}
.addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, buildGoogleSignInOptions(googleAuthId))
.build()
```

How can I know if the `connect()` operation has failed because the Play Services weren't updated?
The `OnConnectionFailed` callback is called only when the user closes the Dialog (that is automatically prompted), but I need a callback in any case to perform some UI operation. Is there a way to achieve that?